# Does S3KeySensor in airflow checks of complete file load?

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

I have a job which writes 20 GB of data (multiple file) in parquet format in s3 and the process takes at least 4-5 minutes. I am using S3KeySensor with wildcard=True for the folder to see file available using S3KeySensor . How can I make sure all the data copy is done so that S3KeySensor can success signal to starts downstream transformation jobs?

s3Filecheck >> Glue job

Answer (score 1):

It does not. The `S3KeySensor` waits for a key to be present in a S3 bucket.

If you are looking to know when upload/transfer of file was completed you need a sensor on that job that sense the job status. You can always write a custom sensor if such one isn't available with Airflow sensors.

Assuming for some reason you can't have a sensor on the job, your closest option is to use the [`S3KeySizeSensor`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f06b3955b1d937138fb38021a6a373b94ae8f9e8/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/sensors/s3.py#L112-L144) which extends the functionality of `S3KeySensor`. The `S3KeySizeSensor` waits for a key to be present and be more than some size in a S3 bucket.